# Wordpress: How to convert a youtube video url to the iframe embed code

Tags: wordpress

I have a WYSIWYG textarea, and sometimes user's may enter a youtube url into the box. On the server side, there are html filters to prevent "harmful" code from being saved.

So instead, I'd like to just keep the server code as-is, and run a jQuery document ready event that searches a block of text for a youtube link, and converts it to the iframe embed code.

I'd imagine it would be regex based, but I'm absolutely horrid with regex's (at some point, I really need to sit down and study them).

Two types of youtube links:

```
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=t-ZRX8984sc
```

or

```
http://youtu.be/t-ZRX8984sc
```

Answer (score -1):

Put this whole block of code into your `functions.php` under your theme directory.

```
function replaceYouTube($string) {
    $pattern = '@(http|https)://(www\.)?youtu[^\s]*@i';
    //This was just for test
    //$string = "abc def http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=t-ZRX8984sc ghi jkm";
    $matches = array();
    preg_match_all($pattern, $string, $matches);
    foreach ($matches[0] as $match) {
        $string = str_replace($match, '<iframe width="560" height="315" src="' . $match . '" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>', $string);
    }
    return $string;
}
add_filter( 'the_content', 'replaceYouTube' );
```

Comment: There are the replacement.

Comment: How to edit     `//$string = "abc def http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=t-ZRX8984sc ghi jkm";`
 for all youtube link.

Comment: You no need to edit, you can simple delete that 2 commented rows. In the `$string`, there will be the content, because of filter. Read about wordpress filters.

Comment: wp_oembed_get($url,$args) can be called codex: https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_oembed_get